# sumif with date criteria in another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to `SUMIF` in another worksheet values having a specific date as criteria.

Like :

```
=SUMIF('Data Form'!G:G,"'Data Form'!1/1/2010",'Data Form'!N:N)
```

I want a specific value in a cell (i.e 1/1/2010) as the criteria in stead of the cell (i.e G8) being the criteria.

**I don't want this:**

```
=SUMIF('Data Form'!G:G,'Data Form'!G6,'Data Form'!N:N)
```

thanks,
Oury

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the date function and there's no need to reference the sheet there!

```
=SUMIF('Data Form'!G:G,DATE(2010,1,1),'Data Form'!N:N)
```